# Wrong designation of variable

Tags: r

I have a variable I named ageyrs for the ages of my 995 research participants. But in R, rather than appear as integer, it is appearing as factor with 75 levels. I wonder what the 75 levels mean, since my participants are 995. I cannot calculate mean age, I keep getting the error message that argument is not numeric or logical. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show the command(s) to import the data and provide a sample of the data. Read the posting guide. The 75 levels means you have _around_ 75 unique ages. I say around because your data is not clean.

Comment: Before you blindly convert the factors into numbers, I highly advise you to explore the data carefully. That may help you to find the reason for the ages being imported as factor.

Comment: You're both right. @Uchechi It should be `as.integer(as.character(ageyrs))`, but actually you should know your data very well before starting to convert them.

Comment: If one of your "ages" is something like `72yo`, then MartinGal's suggestion will convert it to `NA`, which is not what you want. There are techniques for dealing with *this* snafu, but what you need depends on what you have. As Edward said, you likely need to revisit how you import the data, as either the method is wrong or your assumptions of the data to be imported are not correct. Without any more information, all we can offer is (I think) the advice that we just did. Please [edit] your question and add some more context ... but soon, your question will likely be closed. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: I imported the data by clicking on import- from Text base. @ r2evans, you are right that the problem could be from how I imported the data. Is there another way to import it so that R doesn't see the variable as a factor? As for the nature of the ages, there are no characters added to them e.g 72yo, they are all in the integer format. So @ Martin Gal, I wonder why R didn't recognize them as such. @ Edward, is there a way to clean the data? I thought entering the numbers into the spreadsheet (.csv) was the cleaning process

Comment: It's a secondary data analysis I'm doing though. I wonder if the problem was from how the primary researchers entered the data

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help everyone. I had 995 participants. We carefully looked at each entry and found that one of the ages was entered as a range 30-35, and not as a single number. Thank you.